# Mapper attachment issues (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have created mapper attachmet mapping as follow.

```
PUT test-2016.06.11/person/_mapping
{
    "person" : {
        "properties" : {
            "file" : {
                "type" : "attachment",
                "fields" : {
                    "content" : {"store" : "yes"},
                    "title" : {"analyzer" : "chinese", "store" : "yes"},
                    "date" : {"store" : "yes"},
                    "author" : {"analyzer" : "chinese", "store" : "yes"},
                    "keywords" : {"analyzer" : "chinese","store" : "yes"},
                    "content_type" : {"store" : "yes"},
                    "content_length" : {"store" : "yes"},
                    "language" : {"analyzer" : "chinese", "store" : "yes"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I go through the data I put into the index, I could not see any `.raw` field. How should I change my mapping to make  .raw field possible in kibana?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you didn't added any `raw` field.

Comment: How can I add any raw field. I would wanna create field.raw in Kibana for data in mapper attachment like what the logstash will do for input data with default elasticsearch output template.

Comment: I din't work with `kibana` or `logstash` . Just add a "raw" field and set `analyzer : not analyzed` (if you don't want to modify it) or anything else. then work with it.